# Can I set PHP Storms auto complete to only select on tab?

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

I've noticed in the latest version of PHP Storm auto complete getting a little out of hand.

Wherever I type something it suggests things, and that would be fine, but the moment I hit space it selects whatever was selected in the list.  Much of the time it's faster than I can even see the list.

For example, I went to type this string:

"<h3>Can't rate a member at this time.</h3>"

It ends up like this every time:

"<h3>Can't rate $argc member $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA $this time.</h3>"

Faster than I can see the "a" pops up an autocomplete and then I hit space and the first item in the list was "$argc" so it's selected. "at" matches the 'at' in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and "this" is replaced with "$this".

It doesn't only cause a problem with strings, but when I'm working in html and css I come across similar issues.

Currently the only way for me to deal with it is to type slow and keep tapping escape before I press enter which slows things more than the autocomplete helps.

I'd like it to only select if I hit tab but couldn't find shortcuts for selecting in the settings.

I do like the autocomplete and I don't want to turn it off as it is very useful at times, just not when it keeps selecting things I don't need.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Settings | Editor | Code Completion –> Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc**

[image]